# Joining two lists without losing data points - python

Tags: python, dictionary, dataset

I have a Data set with information regarding angles and distances.
When tryin to plot the angles vs distances, I realised that the points were not "organized".
So, I tried to join the two lists (Angles and Distances) in a dictionary and then organize the dictionary by key. in the end, I defined two new lists and attributed to one the keys, and to the other the values.

Like This:

```
x = dict(zip(angle, dist))
new_dict = {}
y = sorted(x.keys())

for i in y:
     new_dict[i] = x[i]

sorted_angle = new_dict.keys()
sorted_dist = new_dict.values()
```

The issue I'm facing is the fact that the length of the original angle list is quite different than the length of sorted_angle.

Am I losing Data Points here? And if so, how can I correct it?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Older pythons (2*) will not preserve the nice sorting when listing .keys(). I suggest this straightforward solution:

```
import numpy as np

ind = np.argsort(dist)
sorted_angle = angle[ind]
sorted_dist = dist[ind]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have duplicate values in the `angle` list, which is the reason why you are seeing the size reduce. The keys of a dictionary have to be unique. If all you wish to do is sort both the lists by `angle`, you could instead do this:

```
sorted_dist = [x for _, x in sorted(zip(angle, dist))]
sorted_angle = sorted(angle)
```

Comment: Yes, I know! I converted it to a np.array before using it, just forgot to write that here. Both originals are the same length (22883) but the length of the new_dict and the "new lists" (sorted_angle and sorted_dist) are a lot smaller (1440). Am I losing data? Like, is there some sort of Python defaul setting that takes out repeated values or so? 
Thank you!

Comment: So,
len(y) = 1440
len(angle) = 22883
len(dist) = 22883

so my guess would be that some data is cutt off when creating the dictionary x!

Comment: I think this should solve your issue. Hope it helps!

Comment: @JoãoRoquetteSaldanha glad it helped! Can I request you to accept this answer, so that this is marked as resolved? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course, I  just didn't knoz how to do it eheh